# How can I compile a C project with multiple files? multiple definition of `resolver' First defined here

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

Here's my exercice. I have to write a function "resolver(double a, double b, double c, double* px1, double *px2);" which determines if the equation ax^2+bx*2+c=0 is of type 1, 2, 3 or 4 (respectively both solutions are eal, solutions are imaginary, solution does not existe, and there's only one solution). This one file called "ec2g.c" does its job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "ec2g.h"

int resolver(double a, double b, double c, double* px1, double *px2){
  double disc = b*b - 4*a*c; /*discriminant helps us know the particular case*/
  int res = 0; /*determines the case we're facing*/
  if (disc >= 0 && a != 0){
    *px1 = (-b + sqrt(disc))/(2*a);
    *px2 = (-b - sqrt(disc))/(2*a);
    res = 1;
  }
  else if (disc < 0){
   *px1 = -b/(2*a);
   *px2 = sqrt(-(disc))/(2*a);
   res = 2;
  }
  else if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c != 0){
   *px1 = 0;
   *px2 = 0;
   res = 3;
  }
  else if (a == 0 && b != 0){
   *px1 = -c/b;
   *px2 = sqrt(-1.0);
   res = 4;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Now, I need another file called "mainEc2g.c" that reads the output from a file called "ecuaciones.txt"...

---

```
1.0 -2.0 1.0
-1.0 -2.0 1.0
3.0 -2.0 -8.0
-3.0 -2.0 -8.0
2.0 3.0 5.0
0.0 0.0 4.0
2.0 0.0 6.0
0.0 4.0 11.0
```

---

And produce this output with the command "./mainEc2g ecuaciones.txt"...

---

```
Caso 1: 1.000000, 1.000000
Caso 1: -2.414214, 0.414214
Caso 1: 2.000000, -1.333333
Caso 2: -0.333333, 1.598611
Caso 2: -0.750000, 1.391941
Caso 3: 0.000000, 0.000000
Caso 2: -0.000000, 1.732051
Caso 4: -2.750000, -nan
```

---

My "mainEc2g.c" file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ec2g.c"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  double a, b, c = 0.0; /*Equation coefficients*/
  double px1, px2; /*Equation results*/
   /* double aux; Helps us store the double we're reading*/
  char  buf[100]; /*Line's maximum size*/
  /*char *token;*/
  int count; /*helps us to get the coefficients*/
  int size;
  int caso; /*helps us determine the case we're facing*/
  if (fp == NULL || argc > 2){
    printf("No such file or many arguments\n");
    return 1;
  }

  while (fgets(buf, 100, fp)){
    count++;
  }
  printf("The file's got %i lines\n", count);
  size = count;
  /*Now, reset count to 0 because we'll need it to get a, b, c and then make use of "resolver"*/
  count = 0;
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  fscanf(fp, "%lf", &a);
  fscanf(fp, "%lf", &b);
  fscanf(fp, "%lf", &c);
  /*printf("a, b, c = %f, %f, %f \n", a, b, c);*/
  caso = resolver(a, b, c, &px1, &px2);
  /*printf("This is case %i\n", caso);*/
  printf("Caso %i: %f, %f\n", caso, px1, px2);
  count++;
  while(count < size){
    fscanf(fp, "%lf", &a);
    fscanf(fp, "%lf", &b);
    fscanf(fp, "%lf", &c);
 /*printf("a, b, c = %f, %f, %f \n", a, b, c);*/
    caso = resolver(a, b, c, &px1, &px2);
    printf("Caso %i: %f, %f\n", caso, px1, px2);
    count++;
  }




/*  while (fscanf(fp, "%f", &aux) != EOF){
    if (count == 0) {
      a = aux;
      printf("El valor de a es: %i\n", a);
      count++;
    }
    else if (count == 1){
      b = aux;
      printf("El valor de b es: %i\n", b);
      count++;
    }
    else if (count == 2){
      c = aux;
      printf("El valor de c es: %i\n", c);
      count++;
    }
    else{
      count = 0;
      caso = resolver(a, b, c, &px1, &px2);
      printf("Caso %i: %f, %f\n", caso, px1, px2);
    }
  }*/

  return 0;
}
```

However, when I use the command `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror mainEc2g.c ec2g.c -o mainEc2g -lm` to compile, this error pops up:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccePNwsS.o: in function `resolver':
ec2g.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `resolver'; /tmp/ccO6EnFU.o:mainEc2g.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve it? By the way, I DO have a header file called "ec2g.h" containing this:

```
#ifndef _EC2G_H_
#define _EC2G_H_

int resolver(double a, double b, double c, double* px1, double *px2);

#endif
```

I tried everything... but can't seem to make it right. I hope I explained myself clearly

Comment: `#include "ec2g.c"` Don't `#include` c files. Do include the header with the function prototype where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should realize what #include does: it literally replaces itself with the file that you specified.

In your case, you place your complete ec2g.c in your mainEc2g.c. then you compile that. Now, all the text from the former are in the latter, and as your linker later tells you, that's duplicate - because of you also compiling ec2g.c separately.

So, NEVER include a .c file in another one. Include the .h, which only defines the function priorities, not the actual function code, in both. Compile the two files to .o files (gcc -c), then combine these to an executable.

Comment: Done. It works. Now, how do I get the output if the teachers want us to do the command "./mainEc2g < ecuaciones.txt"?

Comment: you run exactly that!

Comment: No, when I introduce that command the error "No such file or many arguments" pops up...

Comment: When I run 

./mainEc2g < ecuaciones.txt

this is the result I get with the code:

./mainEc2g < ecuaciones.txt
No such file or many arguments

Comment: @MiguelÁngel If you Google `redirection operators` and look over a few of the websites returned, I think you'll get a better understanding of how to do it.

Comment: @MiguelÁngel If your computer says there's a file missing, then some file is missing. I.e., either you're not in the directory where your `mainEc2g` executable is, or your `ecuaciones.txt` isn't there.